# How to delete “Other” and “Apps” data files in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, osx-yosemite

I am on Mac OS X 10.10 (Yosemite) and can’t for the life of me figure out how to get rid of a bunch of junk that has accumulated on my MacBook Air.

I only use my Mac for word processing and some light iOS development so it should be nowhere near full, but I am just getting a message saying disk storage is full. **How can I delete the “Other” and “Apps” data I see here?**

I saw something saying I should use the `Library` but I don’t even have that option. And how can I stop all these “Apps” from downloading all this junk in the first place? I assume it all comes from webbrowsing and downloads I’m not even consenting to.

What I've tried:

- looking for the `Library` no luck.
- Searching for the `Library` again no luck.
- Deleting stuff I don't recognize in the`All My Files` Finder tab.

Nothing has helped. I'd really appreciate info on how to delete this garbage and/or how to find the `Library`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you're having problems locating what's taking up so much room you can use a tool called [Disk Inventory X](http://derlien.com) that scans your drive and creates a tree structure based on size.

You can then locate the files that are filling up your MacBook Air and delete them as you see fit.

It also has a pretty neat GUI that shows how your drive is split up.

Also if you are still set on finding the `Library` I think the reason you can't find it is that it's a hidden folder. What you need to do is go into the Terminal (“Finder -> Applications -> Utilities”) and type in the following:

> defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles YES

Then you will be able to see all hidden files on your system. Once you are done you can hide them again by typing the following:

> defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles NO

Comment: I know, that's why I suggested Disk Inventory X to see what is taking up so much room in the Apps. I'm just showing him/her how to get to the Library as they requested, perhaps they have some bloat ware that installed there.

Answer (score 0):

First, I have to address this:

> Nothing has helped. I'd really appreciate info on how to delete this
>   garbage and/or how to find the `Library`.

Sorry to be blunt, but you absolutely, positively need to get over the idea you can manually cleanup—or purge—your systems’s `Library` directory and it will solve the problem. It won’t even if you believe you are careful in your assessment of files in that directory. Why? Read on:

#### You cannot randomly expect to cleanup “Other” and “Apps” data as if those directories are unnecessary.

> How can I delete the “Other” and “Apps” data I see here?

Just blanketly deleting items in “Other” and “Apps” will only cause you more headaches and possibly a dead system. Here is why in a most simple/high-level explanation:

Apple’s goal in Mac OS X and even iOS is to make the system you are using seem as simple as possible. Thus the image you show where you see space taken up by “Other”, “Apps”, “Photos”, “Audio” and “Movies” is really oversimplifying things. Here is why:

- For “Photos”, “Audio” and “Movies” that graph is most likely 100% accurate or close to accurate. And on many systems those “Photos”, “Audio” and “Movies” bars/percentages might be as low as 0%.
- But for “Other” and “Apps”, this bars/percentages will 100% *never* be zero or close.

That is because even on a clean/virginal system straight out of the box, “Other” and “Apps” will consist of core Mac OS X system items and applications. Dumping all of the “Other” and “Apps” will just render your MacBook Air effectively braindead. And I am quite positive the `Library` directory is a part of that “Other” bar/percentage.

#### What can you do to free space?

Easy. If space is filling up seemingly randomly, it could be from system caches and logs growing after time. The simplest and easiest way to clear up your system when this happens is to run a cleaning tool like [Onyx](http://www.titanium.free.fr/onyx.html):

> OnyX is a multifunction utility for OS X which you can use to verify
>   the startup disk and the structure of its system files, to run
>   miscellaneous tasks of cleaning and system maintenance, to configure
>   some hidden parameters of many of Apple’s applications, and more.

The part of Onyx I use regularly in situations like this is the “Cleaning” tab.

[image]

I basically check off pretty much everything in the “System,” “User,” “Internet” and “Logs” categories, have Onyx do it’s thing and then reboot my Mac OS X setup. How much space? Depends on how many cache items need to be purged, but you can definitely notice space being freed up before running Onyx and rebooting compared to the results afterwards.

If you are apprehensive about doing this, just start off by cleaning out the “Internet” and “Logs” stuff and see what happens. Then move onto “System” and “User” once you feel safe using Onyx.

But I have personally been using it on my own personal Mac OS X system since Mac OS X 10.5 and client systems as well and I have never had a negative result when running it.

Comment: thanks for this suggestion. I downloaded Onyx and went with their maintenance recommendations. Now some of the app projects I've worked on seem to have lost their attached image files (pngs and jpgs), which is pretty annoying/time consuming to fix. I don't know if there's something strange about how my apps were set up that resulted in this, but would caution people using Onyx about this possibility.

Comment: that's also a negative. I just got another startup file warning today after running Onyx yesterday.

Comment: I've just confirmed that *every* Xcode project on my Mac Air is now missing all its image files. This definitely happened from running Onyx because earlier yesterday I had run some, and now they won't even compile, and I have verified that the files are physically missing. Thanks for the advice, but I just can't see what else it could have been.

Comment: clearly not your fault, but wanted to pass on the useful info. I am so not a fan of Mac OS and Xcode for reasons like this, sadly.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to clear up a lot of disk space that I had a sense was not really being used efficiently.

I found a lot of promos for custom apps.  While, if free (even if not), I have nothing against these, I just would rather find more generic solutions.

Two that I found were most useful were:

1. From Terminal, analyze what is taking up your disk space starting with the command:

   sudo du -hd 1 /

Then for each suspect sub-folder try something like:

```
sudo du -hd 1 /private
```

2. In the case of /private and perhaps other places taking up a lot space, one solution is amazing simple:

**Boot up in safe mode (Reboot while holding down the SHIFT key).**

This will clear out a lot of temporary system files.  This cleared about 18 Gigabytes for me.